# On-Chain-Off-Chain Synchronization

Tags: ethers.js, dapps, dapp-development, synchronization

What are the best ways you have come across (or are doing) to take on-chain data and create off-chain data while avoiding synchronization bugs?

I am interested to see multiple approaches to this as I discovered a hard bug to find. Essentially, I was anticipating a tx to be finalized when it wasn't because of a re-org leading me to update my Dapp erroneously. This wasn't caught locally because re-orgs don't happen locally :/

Additional Context:

- This whitepaper explains this common pitfall well: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.09440
- I am not running my own node for this bug to occur

Answer (score 0):

Developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

Have you tried [theGraph](https://thegraph.com/en/)? It is a neat indexing technology for EVMs. It can definitely handle reorg and other chain-related problems.

But they are discontinuing their hosted service recently for their newly launched theGraph [network](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/network/overview/). I think you need to have their tokens to try their service now.

Anyway, you can still deploy a node locally without a cost or try [our hosting service](https://chainstack.com/subgraphs/), it is in EA stage now.

Comment: I should clarify I am not looking for a service. Just queries to a contract, get result, and store it.